# Two paths having only exactly one vertex in common

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to show that in every graph there exist two paths having only one  vertex in common ? These paths should traverse different vertices except the last one (destination )

Comment: If your graph has zero edge, it won't have two pathes at all...

Comment: I think you are missing some assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a path is a trail with no repeated edges. A trail may consist of a single vertex. Therefore there always are two (identical) paths consisting of exacty one vertex that is the same for both paths. These paths have exactly one vertex in common, and this vertex is the last one for both paths.